# How is the conditional used?

Tags: c, if-statement, escaping

What does the following condition in the following C code means?

```
if (line[currChar] == '\"')
```

Answer (score 5):

It check whether the character in line[currChar] is " or not. It is still **"**, though it is escaped by **\** .

Answer (score 1):

When asking for help, it's usually best to show the declaration/initialization of variables in the code, it helps when answering the questions.

Anyway, presumably `line` is a character array, and `currChar` is an int.

```
int currChar;
char line[] = "Looking for a \" in the code\n");

for(currChar = 0; currChar < strlen(line); currChar++)
    if(line[currChar] == '\"')
        break;
if(currChar < strlen(line))
     printf("we found a \"!");
```

Here's a quick example of how to use that conditional. The `'\'` character in the string is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_sequences_in_C). So if we want to print a `"` in the string you need to escape it, or else it will act as the end of the string (see the initialization of `line[]` above).

When checking for the character `"` you don't need it:

```
if(line[currChar] == '\"')  // This works...
if(line[currChar] == '"')    // so does this
```

because `"` is not going to cause issues when there's no matching quote, but if you wanted to check here for a `'` character, you'd need one.